# MBSAS Clustering Algorithm C++ implementation using DIBLOOK

Tags: c++, algorithm, image-processing, cluster-computing, sequential

I have to implement the [image]BSAS Clustering algorithm for Image Processing.(Basic Sequential Algorithmic Scheme).

I found the pseudo-code for it and i tried some implementation of my own, here is what i have so far:

I am having problems with understanding part of this code, please tell me what i am doing wrong....

```
struct pointInfo {
        POINT p;
        bool isLabeled;
    };

    struct cluster{
        int label;
        vector<POINT> points;
    };

int nrOfClusters = 0;
        int nrPoints;
        int maxClusters;
        float treshold=2;//assign this to a value
        struct cluster clusters[1000];
        struct pointInfo points[1000];

        //save all the black points 
        for (int i = 0; i < dwHeight; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < dwWidth; j++){
                if(lpSrc[i*w+j]==0){
                    points[nrPoints].p.x=i;
                    points[nrPoints].p.y=j;
                    points[nrPoints].isLabeled=false;
                    nrPoints++;
                }
            }

            //MBSAS
            nrOfClusters = 1;
            clusters[nrOfClusters].label = nrOfClusters;
            clusters[nrOfClusters].points.push_back(points[0].p);
            points[0].isLabeled=true;

            for(int i=1;i<nrPoints;i++){
                //find Ck:d(xi,Ck) = min1<j<m d(xi,Cj)
                int distance;//=...
                if(distance>treshold && nrOfClusters<maxClusters){
                    nrOfClusters++;
                    clusters[nrOfClusters].label=nrOfClusters;
                    clusters[nrOfClusters].points.push_back(points[i].p);
                }
            }

            //Pattern Classification
            for(int i=0;i<nrPoints;i++){
                if(points[i].isLabeled==false){
                    //find Ck:d(xi,Ck) = min1<j<m d(xi,Cj)
                }
            }
```

Comment: `I am having problems with understanding part of this code` What part, what problems? I am having problems understanding your question

Comment: `find Ck:d(xi,Ck) = min1<j<m d(xi,Cj)` - this part of the algorithm